# c++ clone class object function

Tags: c++, oop

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A {
    char *str;
public:
    A(): str(new char[20]) {
        str[0] = '\0';
    }
    A(char const *str): str(new char[20]) {
        strcpy(this->str, str);
    }
    A(A const &a): str(new char[20]) {
        strcpy(str, a.str);
    }
    ~A() {
        delete[] str;
    }
    A clone() {
        return *this;
    }
    A copy() {
        return A(*this);
    }
    void print() {
        cout << str << endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    A a("hello"), b, c;
    a.print();
    b = a.clone();
    b.print();
    c = a.copy();
    c.print();
    cout << "Done!" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

i built this simple program just to demonstrate the problem im having.

the output is

```
hello
 n
 n
Done!
```

basically both clone and copy fail to generate a copy of the object

debugging the code reveals that the destructor on the new object is called just before the function returns, which make sense because the scope where the object was created collapse. but then again the returned value not supposed to be copied before destruction??

so how to return an object from a function without destroying it?

Comment: Bare pointer as a member variable = welcome to hell!

Comment: there are copies, but you fail to implement the [rule of 5/3/0](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three) correctly which messes up with your expectations

Comment: you don't have proper `operator =`